# Automate findViewById to get an array of widgets

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm working on a Sodoku app. And it has 81 text. I can use findViewById to get them manually but I'm too lazy and I prefer to have them all in an array. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build up your view programmatically, rather than via an xml file, so that you can grab the instances of the items as you create them.

Comment: I had considered this but the second question is that can I nest these new widgets into other views loaded from the xml or do I have to create the whole UI from the code?

Comment: You can add them to any ViewGroup (Layout) even if you got the reference to that layout from xml.

Answer (score 0):

you can load them into an ArrayList. Or do like @Mayra says and create them programatically in your java.

> but I'm too lazy

Im sorry, but if you're too lazy to think about other ways to solve your own challenges why should we be motivated help you?

Comment: I'm too lazy to do do the first thing that came to mind (Ctrl+C & Ctrl+V) and instead try the second and third ideas (google and ask). Doesn't mean I don't *think* about it. Besides, I believe it's generally a good thing for coder to be lazy (of course within reasonable limit) Otherwise, hey, who need MathLab when you can crunch numbers out using paper and pencil.